# Linked List Deep Copy Problems

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am having trouble with overloading the operator =.

```html
template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
  T m_data;                  // Data to be stored
  Node<T>* m_next;     // Pointer to the next element in the list


  // Purpose: Default constructor
  // Postconditions: next pointer set to NULL
  // ---INLINE---
  Node() : m_next(NULL) {}

  // Purpose: Auxiliaty constructor, construct from parameters
  // Postconditions: data and next pointer set to parameters
  // ---INLINE---
  Node(const T& x, Node<T>* p) 
             : m_data(x), m_next(p) {}

};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
 
public:

  Node<T>* head;     // Pointer to the head of the list

    // Purpose: Default constructor
    // Postconditions: head pointer set to NULL
    // ---INLINE---
  LinkedList() : head(NULL) {}

// --------
// ---- Big 3 Member Functions ---
// --------

// Purpose: Destructor
// IMPORTANT:: For didactic purposes, the destructor is left empty.
// YOU are expected to implement function clear() to de-allocate the list
 // --INLINE
  ~LinkedList() {}

// Purpose: performs a deep copy of the data from rhs into this linked list
// Parameters: rhs is linked list to be copied
// Returns: *this
// Postconditions: this list contains same data values (in the same order)
//     as are in rhs; any memory previously used by this list has been
//     deallocated.
  const LinkedList<T>&  operator= (const LinkedList<T>& rhs);

// Purpose: copy constructor
// Parameters: rhs is the LinkedList that is to be copied
// Postconditions: this list contains same data values (in same order) 
//      as in rhs.
  LinkedList(const LinkedList<T>& rhs);
```

Those are the above given. My current implementation does not provide a deep Copy.

```html
template<class T>
const LinkedList<T>& LinkedList<T>::operator =(const LinkedList<T>& rhs)
{
 if(this != &rhs)
 {
   if(head != NULL)
   {
     clear();
   }
   Node<T>* current = rhs.head;
   while (current != NULL)
   {
     insert_front(current -> m_data);
     current = current -> m_next;
   }
   head = current;
 }  
 return(*this);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Assignment operator returns non-const reference.

Comment: In addition to this, you should be implementing the copy constructor and destructor before implementing the assignment operator.  Why?  Because when you leave the assignment operator for last, it is trivial to implement by using the existing copy constructor and destructor.